# at command does not work

Tags: shell, unix, at-command

When I run this code the shell script does not work.

```
 sudo at -t 200201010102 -f /test.sh
```

The output of `date` command is:

```
Tue Jan  1 01:00:01 IRST 2002
```

The script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
shutdown -r now
```

The user that I run the `at` is test. I give the permission in sudoers file to the user test.

when i run the command it has no error. At the given time I execute `atq` and the job disappear correctly.

what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the following date-time format:

> at -t 200201010210 -f /test.sh

Run the job at time, given in the format YYYYMMDDhhmm[.ss].
YYYY-year(2002)
MM-month(01)
DD-day(01)
hhmm-hour(02:10)

If this doesn't work,then let us know the error captured while executing the command.

Comment: @Sneha.NazareI edit the question. Thanks for your help.